# How to calculate correlation of column with different number of rows?

Tags: pandas, numpy, correlation

Example

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a2 = [2,3,5,6]
```

How to calculate correlation coefficient of this types of columns

Comment: Does https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html help?

Comment: Trim the list to the same length? What is the expected output?

Comment: @mozway i was studying about correlation, i dont have a much knowledge about it. assume if a1 = [1,2,NaN,4,5,NaN] and a2=[2,NaN,6,NaN,10], how to find corr. in this type of data...

Comment: @mlang yes i've used df.corr() but it treats less shorter array by imputing NaN and after that calculating corr. But in this also pandas is able to create a perfect correlation, i want to understand how that NaN is treated and giving right result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trimming the lists to a common length and using [`numpy.corrcoeff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html):

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a2 = [2,3,5,6]

n = min(len(a1), len(a2))

r = np.corrcoef(a1[:n], a2[:n])[0, 1]
```

Output: `0.9899494936611666`